# How to convert dataframe to avro using schema?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

How to convert a dataframe into Avro format using a user-specified schema?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) module that allows for reading and writing Avro data from Spark SQL.

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("user.avsc"))
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
spark
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .option("avroSchema", schema.toString)
  .load("src/test/resources/episodes.avro")
```